Why I'm not able to send xlsx and docx media file on whatsapp using twilio api
Successfully sent images (png,jpeg) and pdf file but when i try to send doc,docx,xlsx etc file then twilio giving error 12300
Twilio is unable to process the Content-Type of the provided URL. Please see Twilio's  documentation on accepted content types  for more information on valid Content-Types.
I'm following this document of twilio: https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api
            $whats_app_twilio_arr = [
                "mediaUrl" => [PORTAL_URL . "/" . $dir . "/" . $newname],
                "from" => "whatsapp:" . WHATS_APP_NO
            ];

            if ($msg) {
                $whats_app_msg_twilio_arr = [
                    "from" => "whatsapp:" . WHATS_APP_NO,
                    "body" => $msg
                ];
                
            }
        } else {
            $whats_app_twilio_arr = [
                "from" => "whatsapp:" . WHATS_APP_NO,
                "body" => $msg
            ];
        }

        if (!empty($whats_app_msg_twilio_arr)){
            $message1 = $twilio->messages->create("whatsapp:" . $phone_no, $whats_app_msg_twilio_arr);
        }

        $message = $twilio->messages->create("whatsapp:" . $phone_no, $whats_app_twilio_arr);



Please note that media file types you mentioned are, as of now, not supported.
You can find all supported MIME types in the docs:

The Twilio API for WhatsApp supports sending and receiving images, audio, PDF files, and video. The following formats are currently supported:

Images: JPG, JPEG, PNG, WEBP*
Audio: OGG**, AMR, 3GP, AAC, MPEG
Documents: PDF, DOC, DOCX, PPTX, XLSX
Video: MP4 (with H.264 video codec and AAC audio)
Contacts: vCard (.vcf)


